# Merge 2 arrays into one with a balanced 2-1 ratio

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have 2 arrays ....lets call them red_array and blue_array and what I would like to do is create a final_array that has a 1 to 2 ratio of blue_array items to red_array aka

```
array[]=  { BLUE_ARRAY_ITEM , RED_ARRAY_ITEM, RED_ARRAY_ITEM, 
BLUE_ARRAY_ITEM,RED_ARRAY_ITEM, RED_ARRAY_ITEM, BLUE_ARRAY_ITEM}  ....ect on`
```

Whats the best way to go about this ?Here is what I started with trying, but all it gives me is a unexpected_token error

```
           $total_count=count($blue_query)+count($red_query);

           $count=0;
           $blue_count=0;
           $red_count=0;
           while ($count <= $total_count) {

                if($blue_count<=50){
                    $finished_array[]=$blue_query[$blue_count];
                    $blue_count++;
                    $count++;
                }

                if($red_count<=50){
                    $finished_array[]=$red_query[$red_count];
                    $red_count++;
                    $count++;
                    $finished_array[]=$red_query[$red_count];

                    $red_count++;
                    $count++;
                }


           }
```

Comment: From the looks of it, your `if` will never be entered because you are checking `$blue_count>=50` when `$blue_count` is 0 at start and never incremented without the `if`. Also your `while` is looping infinite because of not incrementing `$count`.

Comment: edited but still seems to be infinitely looping....am i still not incrementing properly?

Comment: Could you paste the contents of `$blue_query` and `$red_query`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try -

```
<?php
$blue = array(1,4,7,10);
$red = array(2,3,5,6,8,9);

$final_array = array();

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($blue); $i++)
{
    if($i < sizeof($blue))
    {
       $final_array[] = $blue[$i];
    }

    if(($i*2) < sizeof($red))
    {
       $final_array[] = $red[$i*2];
       $final_array[] = $red[($i*2)+1];
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($final_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<pre>Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
   [3] => 4
   [4] => 5
   [5] => 6
   [6] => 7
   [7] => 8
   [8] => 9
   [9] => 10
)
```

**DEMO**

http://3v4l.org/S4jVS

Comment: This does work, however you are still throwing undefined offset notice. They aren't Warnings or Fatal errors, only notices. I would recommend using [`array_key_exists()`](http://us3.php.net/array_key_exists) to solve this problem. Errors like this can clutter a logfile and that's the last thing you want to have when debugging.

Comment: Compared to the other answer, at first I did not like this answer. Dint seem as witty as the first answer, but I can confirm it did work like butter and the other did not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to merge 2:1 and then append all remaining items to the end

```
$b_size = sizeof($blue_arr);
$r_size = sizeof($red_arr);
$size = $b_size + $r_size;
$b_index=0;
$r_index=0;
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    if($b_index >= $b_size) {
        $result[$i] = $red_arr[$r_index];
        $r_index++;
    } else if($r_index >= $r_size) {
        $result[$i] = $blue_arr[$b_index];
        $b_index++;
    } else {
        if($i % 3 == 0) {
            $result[$i] = $blue_arr[$b_index];
            $b_index++;
        } else {
            $result[$i] = $red_arr[$r_index];
            $r_index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Use this if you would like to stop when one of the array's items are exhausted

```
$b_size = sizeof($blue_arr);
$r_size = sizeof($red_arr);
$size = $b_size + $r_size;
$b_index=0;
$r_index=0;
for($i=0; ($b_index < $b_size) || ($r_index < $r_size); $i++) {
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        $result[$i] = $blue_arr[$b_index];
        $b_index++;
    } else {
        $result[$i] = $red_arr[$r_index];
        $r_index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this seemed solid to me in theory , but for some reason it gives me  "undefined offest" error for this line: $result[$i] = $red_arr[$r_index];

Comment: small mistake `$b_index > $b_size` has to be `$b_index >= $b_size`. same for red. Updated my anser

Answer (score 1):

wrote this code to get 3:2 ratio between blue and red, i.e. 3 blue and 2 red

```
    $final_array = array();
    $count = sizeof($blue);
    if(sizeof($red) > sizeof($blue)){
        $count = sizeof($red);
    }

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        if(($i*3) < sizeof($blue))
        {
           $final_array[] = $blue[$i*3];
           if(isset($blue[($i*3)+1])){
                $final_array[] = $blue[($i*3)+1];
                if(isset($blue[($i*3)+2])){
                    $final_array[] = $blue[($i*3)+2];
               }
           }
        }

        if(($i*2) < sizeof($red))
        {
           $final_array[] = $red[$i*2];
           if(isset($red[($i*2)+1])){
                $final_array[] = $red[($i*2)+1];
           }
        }
    }
```